# Undeclared identifier TIdServerIOHandlerSSL

Tags: delphi, ssl, soap, indy

I'm doing maintenance in a Delphi project, but I don't know this language very much, and when I try to build the code with Embarcadero RAD Studio I get the following error:

`Undeclared identifier 'TIdServerIOHandlerSSL'`

I did some research and it looks like `TIdServerIOHandlerSSL` is part of a library called "Indy", but even though I have Indy 10 installed on my RAD Studio, I still get the error.

In the project folder, someone left two files named as `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll` and I've tried to copy them into the System32 folder following this instructions:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/OpenSSL but the error persists.

So, I don't know how to get this class and **ANY** help will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe `TIdServerIOHandlerSSL` was used in Indy v9 but your RAD studio comes with Indy v10... (not 100% sure here)

Comment: @whosrdaddy Looks like you're probably right. That component doesn't exist in Delphi 10.1 Berlin. Must be an Indy version issue.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try to install Indy v9 on RAD Studio and see what happens. Thank you guys! :)

Comment: @Lion I wouldn't recommend trying that. The one time I attempted to install a different Indy version than was already there, it failed miserably. Instead, you should adapt to the version you already have pre-installed. Specifically its replacement `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL`. Especially if you're not too familiar with Delphi.

Comment: Indeed, Indy 9 is not compatible with recent Delphi versions, you should migrate to Indy 10. Another (IMHO better) option is to build the code in the Delphi version it was written for as there may be other migration issues...

Comment: whosrdaddy and Jerry are both right.  The code in question was written for Indy 9, which does not support Delphi 2009+, so either migrate the project+code to Indy 10, or use a pre-2009 version of Delphi with Indy 9.

Comment: indeed both are right, but I think I'll follow @whosrdaddy 's advice because I'm not too familiar neither with Delphi nor with the project itself and I'll struggle a lot to adapt it, the problem now is to install Delphi 7, I saw lots of people struggling to find Delphi 7 to download, any advice about where to find it?

Comment: @Lion, if you have a paid version of RAD Studio, then you can download the Delphi 7 iso from the registered users download page.

Comment: Don't copy DLLs into your system directory. That's never a good idea. Don't use random ssl DLLs either. Do you know what version they are? Do you know what security defects are present in them?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: its funny that the documentation actually advises to copy OpenSSL DLL's into the system path...

Comment: @who imagine what happens when you want to use two programs that want different versions of these DLLs. Nobody ever found dll hell funny.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, been there, done that ;) Procmon and Depwalk are my daily friends...

Comment: I've installed Delphi 7 and now I don't have problems with that class anymore (I have another problems though, but nothing related to that). So thanks you all, everybody helped a lot! :)